# how to i manage textviews inside linear layout orientation horizontal

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

[image]

**Code :**

```
LinearLayout linearLayout2;

final JSONArray answer=jsonObject1.getJSONArray("answer");  
 //Here get Answer from question

    ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2)).removeView(linearLayout2);                   //Here remove preselected radiobuttons
    linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(TestActivity2.this);                                       //Here create new viewgroup when user click next and previous
    linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout2.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);

    indexAns=new String[answer.length()];

    for(int j=0;j<answer.length();j++)
    {
        final JSONObject jsonObject2 = answer.getJSONObject(j);
        final String answer_ans=jsonObject2.getString("answer_ans");                            //get answer from loop

        answer_id=jsonObject2.getString("answer_id");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //Here create radio buttons depending on answer loop
        final TextView textBtn = new TextView(TestActivity2.this);
        textBtn.setId(Integer.parseInt(answer_id));
        textBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
        textBtn.setAllCaps(true);
        textBtn.setTextSize(12);
        textBtn.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        textBtn.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER |Gravity.RIGHT);
        textBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        indexAns[j]=answer_id;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What's your question?

Comment: @Abhishek take your time format your your code address your issue with steps by updating your question we are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post your layout xml files.  Looks like you are manipulating the layout programatically, which, in most cases in unnecessary.  You can accomplish the same goal via xml layout files.

Also, you can save a lot of time using styles for formatting.

Check out the following layout documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Check out the TextView documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html